# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Recovery'

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I tried to filter the data points, it seems like the filtration does not work quite well, and I am really confused cause last time when I used literally the same codes, it worked. Attached below is the filtration part and the error description.

```
"""------------- Read all the data points in the file ----------------------------------------"""
zeolite_13X_error = pd.read_csv("zeolite_13X_error.csv", delimiter=",")  # Used for training set
zeolite_copy = zeolite_13X_error.copy()  # Used for test set
"""--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

"""------------- Filter points, Recovery rate and Purity - Test Set Only ---------------------"""
zeolite_13X_error_testset = zeolite_copy[zeolite_copy.Recovery > 0.7]
zeolite_13X_error_testset = zeolite_13X_error_testset[zeolite_13X_error_testset.Purity > 0.7]
zeolite_13X_error_testset = zeolite_13X_error_testset[zeolite_13X_error_testset.Recovery < 1.0]


*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/julia/Machine Learning Edi/Combination Prediction.py", line 16, in <module>
    zeolite_13X_error_testset = zeolite_copy[zeolite_copy.Recovery > 0.7]
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda3\envs\Machine Learning Edi\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Recovery'*
```

Comment: You try to access the `Recovery` column, but it does not exist. Check the names of the columns in your dataframe.

Comment: Well, thanks, it actually exists because in the later scripts, I can extrapolate data values from that column I persume

Comment: @YulinWang - Are you sure that the column exists?? If so, try not using the dot notation and use `zeolite_13X_error_testset['Recovery']` and `zeolite_copy['Recovery']`